# Joomla 3.0: pass parameter to edit form

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

This is my problem: I need to pass a parameter to edit form of joomla, so link will be like this: https://mydomain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_mycom&task=mycom.edit&type=country&id=233.
The param "type" must be send to my edit form. But i cannot get it by this way in my **"view.html.php"** file

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input 
$type = $input->getVar("type");
```

Cause the link always remove the "type" param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link you mentioned link executes controller method edit in `com_mycom/controllers/mycom.php` that extends `JControllerForm` where things happens like item check-in, ACL checks, etc. and user might be redirected to the edit form (see [JControllerForm::edit](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/legacy/controller/form.php#L375)).

Anything but table key (usually item id) is stripped out from the query.

Copy over default edit method to your subcontroller and modify to read things you want

```
public function edit($key = null, $urlVar = null)
{
    $app   = JFactory::getApplication();
    $type  = $app->input->get->('type', null');

    //...
```

Later on in redirect for new and existing items append `'&type=' . $type` to url query

```
$this->setRedirect(
    JRoute::_(
        'index.php?option=' . $this->option . '&view=' . $this->view_list . '&type=' . $type
```

Comment: Thanks from 8 years later, to you and the asker for helping me figure out where my query params were getting gobbled up. Instead of completely overriding, what I did was call `parent::edit($key, $urlVar)` and then if that returned `true` I'd override the redirect using `$this->setRedirect`. Not saying this is a better way (maybe it's unnecessary overhead) but if changes are made to the method, this won't override them.